# How to set up a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework designer thingy

Tags: entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I'm an NHibernate developer trying to give Entity Framework a shot in a hobby project. I'm used to specifying mapping data in code using Fluent NHibernate. Pardoning Microsoft's belief that developers shouldn't be allowed to write code, I'm trying to create my mappings using the Entity Framework's visual designer surface (which you get by opening the .edmx file in Visual Studio).

I have no idea how to set up a many-to-many relationship! I have 'updated the model' from the database, but I get two one-to-many relationships with a new entity corresponding to the junction table (which contains only foreign keys and its own primary key).

So far, all attempts at working this out by clicking on the entities and relationships and such have failed. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your junction table must be what MS calls a '[pure join table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742359.aspx)' - it must contain *only* the two foreign keys, and no other columns.  In your case, that means you must delete the primary key column.

Comment: My heavens. Really? I keep hitting these arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: A join table's primary key would be compund and consist of both foreign keys.  It's a good "normal" db design habit to have for this type of table.

Comment: Also, it's not an 'arbitrary' restriction.  If you have any additional columns then EF needs an entity to store those properties in, hence the intermediary entity.

Comment: I think it's reasonably typical for a 'pure' join table to have its own primary key as well as the foreign keys. Normal enough for EF to anticipate the scenario.

Comment: Is this 'limitation' (i.e. the requirement that there is no separate primary key) a limitation of the model updating functionality, a limitation of the visual design surface, or of EF's mapping capability in general? Put another way, could I amend the .edmx XML manually to create a many-to-many mapping even though I have a separate primary key?

Comment: I think it depends on what exactly your design methodology is.  If you are truly doing Database-first then EF will need an Entity to store that primary key ID column in.  If you want to use the EDMX as your starting point (model-first) then you woul re-create the relationship as a many-to-many in the EDMX but know that the resulting join table it creates will only have two columns in it.

Comment: I'm also not entirley sure what the downstream impact of a true many-to-many relationship would be versus two one-to-many relationships. The visual representation from the EDMX file is just that, a visual representation.  At the database level that join table still has to exist and at the code level I think you would implement updates/edits/deletes the same way in either scenario.

Comment: Okay, I think that's answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you add the association to the model you choose each of your two tables and choose "many" on both sides of the relationship.  When this generates the database script a join table with only the two keys will be created for you.

[image]

By the way:  If you don't like using Model-first and would rather code research "Code-First" development for the Entity Framework.  You can also do Database-First if you prefer that.

Comment: I am starting with a database. But according to ladenedge, my junction table cannot have its own primary key.

Comment: Cool.  That would be known as database-first design then.  Knowing how a framework will translate your database is always tricky.