# How to add or remove a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

There's a many-to-many `UserFeed` table that stands between `User` and `Feed` and denotes a twitter-like follow relationship.
It only has two fields, which form a composite key: `UserID` and `FeedID`.

I need to write a method that will subscribe or unsubscribe a user from a feed based on a boolean flag.

```
public void SetSubscriptionFlag (int userId, int storeId, bool subscribe)
{
}
```

I'm new to Entity Framework so I'm trying to find and follow an "EF-ish" way to accomplish this.

My initial thoughts are:

- Instead of working with the middle `UserFeed` class, I should create a many-to-many `Subscriptions` property (**EDIT:** hit [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116430/how-to-set-up-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-designer-thingy) here);
- After I've done so, I'll need to fetch a `User` instance by ID, check whether it has given `Feed` in its `Subscriptions` and add/delete it depending on the flag and current existence;
- Figure out how to avoid racing conflicts when there is a time interval before the check and adding/deleting and user manages to submit two adding or deletion requests;
- Optimize my code as to avoid unneccessary SELECTs, if any occur, because all I really want to do is a single SELECT and single INSERT/DELETE.

A relevant code snippet and comment on my points is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use dummy objects - it definitely works for insert and I hope it can be used for delete as well:

Create new relation:

```
var user = new User() { Id = userId };
context.Users.Attach(user);
var store = new Store() { Id = storeId };
context.Stores.Attach(store);

// Now context trackes both entities as "existing"
// and you can build a new relation
user.Subscriptions.Add(store);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Remove existing relation:

```
var user = new User() { Id = userId };
var store = new Store() { Id = storeId };
user.Subscriptions.Add(store);
context.Users.Attach(user);

// Now context trackes both entities as "existing"
// with "existing" relation so you can try to remove it
user.Subscriptions.Remove(store);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. But what about concurrency? E.g. a record gets inserted between a check and insert from another request. Is there any common approach?

Comment: Both columns in many-to-many junction table must be marked as primary key so the concurrency will cause the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your replies in this and other threads. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Ladislav. Thanks for your answer. I have a little bit different task. How can all subscriptions for specific user be removed? So there is User ID and I want to remove all subscriptions for this user.

Comment: @bsnote: You should create another question (and probably reference this one if it helps you formulate the problem).

Comment: Hmm, creating the relation results in an error for me because it is trying to insert a new "Store" with null values that are required.