# How do I map Entity Framework many To many table with extra key part?

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to map this so that the parent tables Airport and Flight map to only the relevant part of the foreign composite key?

Using EF4.3 with Code First and Fluid API.

Each flight lands at one or more airports in a specific order. Without the additonal key property of FlightOrder, this mapping works.

```
Airport
- string Code
- List<AirportFlight> AirportFlights

Flight
- string Number
- List<AirportFlight> AirportFlights

AirportFlight
- string AirportCode
- string FlightNumber
- int FlightOrder

public AirportConfiguration() {
    HasKey(x => x.Code);
    HasMany(x => x.AirportFlights).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.AirportCode);
}

public AirportFlightConfiguration() {
    HasKey(x => new { x.AirportCode, x.FlightNumber, x.FlightOrder });
}

public FlightConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(x => x.Number);
    HasMany(x => x.AirportFlights).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.FlightNumber);
}
```

This is Entity Framework generated schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Airports(
Code nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
AirportFlight_AirportCode nvarchar(128) NULL, -- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***
AirportFlight_FlightNumber nvarchar(128) NULL, -- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***
AirportFlight_FlightOrder int NULL, -- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***

CREATE TABLE Flights(
Number nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
AirportFlight_AirportCode nvarchar(128) NULL, -- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***
AirportFlight_FlightNumber nvarchar(128) NULL, -- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***
AirportFlight_FlightOrder int NULL, -- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***

CREATE TABLE AirportFlights(
AirportCode nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
FlightNumber nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
FlightOrder int NOT NULL,
CreatedDate datetime NOT NULL,
RowVersion varbinary(max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_AirportFlights PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    AirportCode ASC,
    FlightNumber ASC,
    FlightOrder ASC
)

ALTER TABLE AirportFlights  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_AirportFlights_Airports_AirportCode FOREIGN KEY(AirportCode)
REFERENCES Airports (Code)

ALTER TABLE AirportFlights  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_AirportFlights_Flights_FlightNumber FOREIGN KEY(FlightNumber)
REFERENCES Flights (Number)

-- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***
ALTER TABLE Airports  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Airports_AirportFlights_AirportFlight_AirportCode_AirportFlight_FlightNumber_AirportFlight_FlightOrder FOREIGN KEY(AirportFlight_AirportCode, AirportFlight_FlightNumber, AirportFlight_FlightOrder)
REFERENCES AirportFlights (AirportCode, FlightNumber, FlightOrder)

-- *** DO NOT WANT THIS ***
ALTER TABLE Flights  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Flights_AirportFlights_AirportFlight_AirportCode_AirportFlight_FlightNumber_AirportFlight_FlightOrder FOREIGN KEY(AirportFlight_AirportCode, AirportFlight_FlightNumber, AirportFlight_FlightOrder)
REFERENCES AirportFlights (AirportCode, FlightNumber, FlightOrder)
```

Thanks.

**Fixed:**

**These properties were in the AirportFlights entity**

```
- List<Airport> Airports
- List<Flight> Flights
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework designer thingy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116430).  Basically, if you need that extra property, you'll have to manage the many-to-many relationship in your business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mapped the join table as an entity, it does not have collection navigational properties to `Airport` and `Flight`. You have to model this as two one-to-many relationships. Remove `List<Airport> Airports` and `List<Flight> Flights`.

```
AirportFlight
- string AirportCode
- string FlightNumber
- int FlightOrder
```

However you can place navigationa proprties `Airport` and `Flight` on `AirportFlight` entity if you want.

Comment: Good and fast catch, I just noticed that and tested successfully with the changes.