# Many to Many Relationship, EDMX shows no primary key warning?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a table **Students** and another one **Subjects**, and a third table **StudentsSubjects**  , and the Students and Subjects table have a many-to-many relationship as you can see in the edmx diagram below.

However, the EDMX file in VisualStudio 2012:

1. doesn't show the **StudentsSubjects** table **AND**
2. shows a warning *"StudentsSubjects" doesn't have a primary key defined but it was inferred.*

[image]

I defined both `StudentId` and `SubjectId` in `StudentSubject` table as foreign keys only (not as primary keys as well). Am I doing it wrong? How do I fix the Visual studio warning above?

Comment: in addition to StudentId and SubjectId in StudentSubject Table, whey not add an Auto incremented int column e.g RecordID and make it an Identity column/PrimaryKey

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior , thats interesting, is that standard/good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour for your question #1 is by design - assuming that your junction table, `StudentsSubjects` has only the 2 columns, being the foreign keys `StudentId` and `SubjectId`, then EF will hide the junction table and instead provide one-to-many navigation from both `Student` and `Subject`. (Microsoft calls this a [Pure Join Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742359.aspx)).

For this EF N:N behaviour to work, no other columns are permitted in the junction table, not even a simple surrogate key (as suggested by `@SQL.Net Warrior`).

To avoid the warning in question #2, the primary key for the junction table would thus need to be the composite key `(StudentId, SubjectId)`, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE StudentsSubjects 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_StudentsSubjects
PRIMARY KEY (StudentId, SubjectId);
```

See also [How to set up a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework designer thingy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116430/how-to-set-up-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-designer-thingy)